# Delay when unhiding UIButtons after presenting SKScene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, sprite-kit

I have encountered a delay/pause that I was not expecting and the reason so far has me scratching my head. I have a simple game setup where the `UIViewController` shows a number of UIButtons [PLAY GAME] [VIEW SCORES] etc. which in turn present a different `SKScene`

My problem is that when I try and set the visibility of these buttons to visible (perviously set to hidden in `viewDidLoad`) from the `UIViewController` they take about 5 seconds to actually show.

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)presentTitleScene {

    // SHOW BUTTONS
    [[self logoLabel] setHidden:NO];
    [[self gameButton] setHidden:NO];
    [[self scoreButton] setHidden:NO];
    [[self creditsButton] setHidden:NO];

    // PRESENT SCENE
    SKScene *titleScene = [TitleScene sceneWithSize:[[self spriteKitView] bounds].size];
    [titleScene setName:@"TITLE_SCENE"];
    [titleScene setScaleMode:SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill];
    [(SKView *)[self view] presentScene:titleScene];
    [self setCurrentScene:titleScene];
}
@end
```

What happens is all the code runs, the `SKScene` presents correctly, then after about 5-6 seconds the buttons appear? Is there anything I can do about this (force an update) or is it just a case of design it out or live with it?

This happens on both the simulator and the device.

## EDIT:

Looking at the output log you can clearly see that after calling `preloadTextureAtlases:withCompletionHandler:` that execution jumps to another thread. The method `preloadTextureAtlases:withCompletionHandler:` is called on the main thread and its supposed to preload the textureAtlas(s) on a background thread, but I was under the impression that the completionHandler would call back onto the main thread, is this assumption right or am I wrong?

## EDIT_002:

Moved to answer below.

Comment: Run the code for displaying the buttons on the main thread.

Comment: I will look into this and get back to you, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: you EDIT is a very good observation, let me know if you found a solution please, thanks

Comment: Question edited to show what was causing the problem ..., thanks to Akshat for his initial comment that put me on the right track, much appreciated.

Comment: @fuzzygoat please post EDIT_002 as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @fuzzygoat yeah, I just checked this. Completion handler runs on background thread. I thought that it should run on main thread, but that's obviously not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to preloadTextureAtlases:withCompletionHandler: the completionHandler gets called on a background thread, I would assume the same one that was used to preload the atlases. The problem that I was having was that I was using the completion handler to send an NSNotification to my viewController saying "the assets have loaded, start the game" The issue with this is that "Notifications are delivered in the same thread that they are sent from" so my game also started in the background thread. As a consequence the code that set the UIButtons to visible was also running on that same background thread, hence the delay in them reacting to either being made visible or hidden.