# How does SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases: withCompletionHandler works?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch, sktextureatlas

I am trying to figure out what is the difference between these two examples and how preloadTextureAtlases :withCompletionHandler works. Here is the code:

```
//GameScene.m
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

   //First I create an animation, just a node moving from one place to another and backward.

   //Then I try to preload  two big atlases



[SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:@[self.atlasA, self.atlasB] withCompletionHandler:^{   
               [self setupScene:self.view];   
       }];
```

I suppose that preloadTextureAtlases doing loading on background thread because my animation is smooth?

But are there any differences(or it can be problematic somehow) to call preloadTextureAtlases from background thread? Like this:

```
//GameScene.m
    - (void)loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:(CompletitionHandler)handler {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
      [SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:@[self.atlasA, self.atlasB] withCompletionHandler:^{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                  [self setupScene:self.view];
                });  
            }];

            if (!handler){return;}
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                handler();
            });
        });
    }
```

And then call this method from didMoveToView:

```
    [self loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:^{

    NSLog(@"Scene loaded");
    // Remove loading animation and stuff

}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preload in the background but the question is why would you? Chances are your game cannot start playing until all required assets are loaded so the user will have to wait regardless.

You can preload whatever assets you need to get the game started and background load any additional assets you might require during later game play. Those kind of circumstances are really only required in very complex games and not on the iOS platform.

As for your question on loading in the background while game play is ongoing, there is no definite answer. It all depends on how big of a load, your CPU load, etc... Try it out and see what happens because it sounds like you are asking questions on issues you have not tried out first.

If you are really intent on background tasks, remember that you can add a completion block to your custom methods like this:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    NSLog(@"start");

    [self yourMethodWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"task done");
    }];

    NSLog(@"end");
}

-(void)yourMethodWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))done; {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // a task running another thread
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            NSLog(@"working");
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (done) {
                done();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Sangony, thanks for hints! Actually I was just about to write an answer to my own question, but never mind. I tried everything. In first example, completion handler of preloadTextureAtlases is called in background thread which I wasn't expected. Because of that, setupScene is called in background. In second example, scene setup is done on the main thread (dispatch_get_main_queue). I thought that there is no difference between those two examples, but there are. Here is one similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534088/delay-when-unhiding-uibuttons-after-presenting-skscene

Comment: I am preloading assets in background, because of an loading animation...That's the only reason. Otherwise, app freezes about 0.5 or 1 sec and loading animation stops.

Comment: The Apple docs for the preloadTextureAtlases explicitly state: "SpriteKit creates a background task that loads the texture data from all of the specified atlases. Then, SpriteKit returns control to your game. After the atlases are loaded, your completion handler is called."

Comment: "You can preload in the background but the question is why would you?" because levels can be big and you have to preload on demand. You cannot preload huge amounts of textures into the memory at once. That's why.

Comment: @damirstuhec - Try reading my entire answer before commenting on it.