# SpriteKit scene transition lag and Frame Rate drop after preloading

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I'm building a game in SpriteKit and have recently ran into problems with my frame rate continually dropping to 50-45 from 60 only in `GameScene`and a couple second lag upon opening the `GameScene` from my `StartScene`. I have tried a bunch of different things and I believe one of my main problems has to do with animating a SKSpriteNode subclass that spawns very frequently, when I stop animating them and instead use a single texture the frame rate stays at 60. I previously [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818210/preloading-textures-in-spritekit) about preloading textures into SpriteKit, and received awesome answers but I may have not fully understood. At this point I have all of my `GameScene` textures in a single Atlas and I load them all in by creating constants for each right before my `GameScene`:

```
//Preload textures of GameScene before running it
let alienTexture1 = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Sprites").textureNamed("alienTexture1")
let alienTexture2 = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Sprites").textureNamed("alienTexture2")
...

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
```

I know that I'm supposed to use:

```
SKTextureAtlas(named: "YourTextureAtlasName").preloadWithCompletionHandler { 
// Now everything you put into the texture atlas has been loaded in memory
}
```

to preload the textures but I'm not sure what goes in between the brackets and when a line like `let alienTexture1 = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Sprites").textureNamed("alienTexture1")` is supposed to be called. These textures are then called inside of the `init` of some Alien SKSpriteNode subclasses that I have. I'm not understanding something because the preload clearly isn't working properly. I'm also not sure what to do about the lag when switching to the `GameScene` but I imagine it also has to do with my way of loading in textures at the beginning with all of those `let` statements. Any advice would be great.

I have looked at other questions on this subject and felt that this was specific enough that it wasn't a repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused on this as well and I am by no means an expert but essentially preloading textures just means you store them in an array/property that will not get deallocated.

I dont really use the SKTextureAtlas("").preloadWithCompletionHandler method. I believe the idea is basically the same.

For example you can create a static texture loading class

```
 class Textures {

      static var alien1 = [SKTexture]() // array off all alien 1 textures


      static func preloadAll() {
           loadAlien1()
           ...
      }

      // Alien 1
      static func loadAlien1() {

           // Get atlas
           let alien1AtlasName = "Your atlas name"
           let alien1Atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: alien1AtlasName)

            // Loop through images in atlas and append to alienTexture property
           // In this case there is 2 images in the atlas)
           // Images should be appended by _1 , _2 etc 
           for image in 1...2 {
               let textureName = "\(alien1AtlasName)_\(image)"
               let texture = alien1Atlas.textureNamed(textureName)
               alien1.append(texture)
           }   
      }
 }
```

When your app launches in appDelegate or GameViewController preload the textures

```
 Textures.preloadAll()
```

If you have a lot of textures and you want to keep memory usages low just preload the Textures you initially need and load other textures for other levels later.

```
  Texture.loadAlien1()
```

Than you can run the animations on your alien 1 characters from your subclass or SKScene like this

```
let textureAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(Textures.alien1, timePerFrame: 0.3)
alien1Sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(textureAnimation), withKey: "Alien1AnimationKey")
```

If you need to clean your textures, incase you no longer need them or if your app gets a low memory warning you just empty the arrays.

```
 Textures.alien1.removeAll()
```

In regards to performance, you should also store your atlas in xCode asset catalogue, which is a new feature in xCode 7, instead of a folder in your project.

Hope this helps